# Form in Form. Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, propel

I use Symfony1.4 and Propel my application.
I have a problem.
For example: I have a database in which I want to keep authors and books. I make the following scheme:
schema.yml

```
book:
    id: ~
    name: {type: varchar (100), required: true}

author:
    id: ~
    name: {type: varchar (100), required: true}

author_book:
    id_book: {type: integer, foreignTable: book, foreignReference: id, required: true, primaryKey: true, onDelete: cascade}
    id_author: {type: integer, foreignTable: author, foreignReference: id, required: true, primaryKey: true, onDelete: cascade}
```

And I want to with the addition of the author, add books that he wrote, without leaving the page for adding the author.
This is an easy question, but for some reason I have not found the solution.
(I think do this by writing a widget that using ajax to load the form of "adding a book", but is not it possible there is a ready solution?)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You'll have to use embedded forms as @PANPELOPE suggests. If you want to use AJAX to load additional forms dynamically you'll have to write the code yourself. It's not very dificult but requires some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sfForm::embedForm()` to embed several form. Look at this doc : http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms, it is explained.

Comment: Thank you. I have one question: What should I do if I want to add the author in the window book, how to specify the book - not yet created the author's id?

Comment: Do you want to add a combo to select the author that's it?

Comment: I write:
`class BookForm extends BaseBookForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
 unset($this['id_author']);
 if(!$this->isNew())
 {
  $this->embedForm('Author', new AuthorForm($this->getObject()->getAuthor()));
 }
 else
 {
  $this->embedForm('Author', new AuthorForm()); 
 }
}`
but "save" does not work because need author's id for book

Comment: I think you have to change `id_author`as a `sfWidgetFormInputHidden` to get it in your action

Comment: I must to override `executeCreate` or `bind` ?

Comment: The action which is called when you click to add